# Can devs view bugs created in MS Test Manager without using test manager?

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager

I want to start using MS Test Manager over our current test case management software for a number of reasons. I like that you can create bugs right from the test case which I thought was a great idea. However, now I am wondering are the devs going to be able to view those bugs without Test Manager? They use visual studio and the same TFS system but would they have access to those bugs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the bugs are just regular bug work items.  You will be able to see them in Visual Studio and Web Access.